# Require in modifier: Undeclared identifier

Tags: solidity, compilation

curious why the require statement throws up Undeclared identifier in this solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Escrow {
    ....
    modifier onlyafter(uint _time) {
      require(now >= _time);
      _;
}
```

I rewrote it as:

```
   modifier onlyafter(uint _time) {
      if(now >= _time){
       throw;}
      _;
}
```

which compiled fine.

Answer (score 6):

`require` is available since Solidity 0.4.10: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases

Since your pragma requires an older Solidity version this leads to a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tried to bump up the version in truffle but it was having none of it. Not a biggie but nice to know.

Comment: truffle sometimes lags a few compiler versions behind. I see that the currently latest version of truffle should ship with Solidity 0.4.11 so you should be fine if you update your `pragma` statement accordingly: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v3.2.2